# Check Email is unique when register

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I've a UserViewModel, and a register form (email, password), so I want to check in backend that email is unique, could you help me a solution function to fix this issue

```
public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public int Role { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
```

```
RuleFor(model => model.Password).NotEmpty().WithMessage(string.Format(Resource.Validation_Required, Resource.Password));
RuleFor(model => model.Password).Must(MustHaveCharacterNumberAndSpecialCharacter).WithMessage(string.Format(Resource.Validation_Password, Resource.Password));

RuleFor(model => model.Email).NotEmpty().WithMessage(string.Format(Resource.Validation_Required, Resource.Email));
RuleFor(model => model.Email).EmailAddress().WithMessage(string.Format(Resource.Validation_Email, Resource.Email));
```

```
  async Task<bool> MustBeUnique(string email, Guid id, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            var user = await userService.GetAsync(x =>
               x.Email.Equals(email, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) &&
               x.Id != id,
                cancellationToken
            );

            return user == null;
        }
```

Comment: You have to make a DB call to check if email exist or not. When you register user at that time first you can check if email is exist in table or not. Based on that you have to give error message or add user in table respectively

Comment: I've edit my post, I've add my function for call db to check email, but error

Comment: Add unique key constraint on the email column in database, try insert, get an exception if it already exists. That's the 'safe' way to ensure there is only ever one of something in a database.

Comment: I dont want to do this way, could you help me give some in asp.net to validation this

Comment: There is no built-in validation method for this. Any solution involves either manually querying the database or relying on a database exception due to a unique constraint violation. Those are your choices.

Comment: I've fixed issue successfully, tks all

Answer (score 0):

I AspNet Core provides a builtin way to specify that an email should be unique when adding the identity provider in your startup class as follows

```
public class Startup {
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole> (options =>
        {
             options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        })
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
    }
}
```

By doing this email for users are check that they are unique when a user signs up in your application

Comment: This is good to add regardless, but the error you'll get back on attempting to create the user does not specifically tell you *why* it failed, i.e. that it was due to an existing same email address. As such, it's not a complete solution to the problem.

Comment: It does tell you why it failed. I just created an ASP NET Core sample application and I tried signing up for the second time add the model error returned was "Email 'email here' is already taken."